# How to disable console logs from react-scroll-to-bottom

Tags: reactjs, react-scroll

I have installed react-scroll-to-bottom.

Everytime I render this component, I have some logs about it in the console.

Do you know how to disable this ? Documentation says to pass debug:{false} as a props to the component, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in that particular package as mentionned here :

https://github.com/compulim/react-scroll-to-bottom/issues/75

Problem will be fixed in the next release.

It seems that setting NODE_ENV to production can do the trick, but it doesn't  work for me.